# How to add custom URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, kaminari

How to add custom URLs like `localhost:3000/one_hour/page/2` instead of `localhost:3000/one_hour?page=2`

to `get '/one_hour', to: 'feed_entries#one_hour'`

I use Rails 4, Kaminari and mongoid

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  concern :paginatable do
    get '(page/:page)', :action => :index, :on => :collection, :as => ''
  end
  resources :feed_entries, path: 'news', :concerns => :paginatable
  get '/one_hour', to: 'feed_entries#one_hour'
end
```

feed_entries_controller.rb

```
class FeedEntriesController < ApplicationController
  one_hour
    @feed_entries = FeedEntry.includes(:source).one_hour.page(params[:page])
  end
end
```

Comment: This is covered in the Kaminari README: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#creating-friendly-urls-and-caching

Comment: @jordan I need it for `get '/one_hour', to: 'feed_entries#one_hour'`

Comment: You have `:on => :collection` I think you want to replace collection with `:feed_entries`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

in routes.rb

`get 'one_hour/(page/:page)', controller: 'feed_entries', action: 'one_hour', to: 'feed_entries#one_hour', as: :one_hour`